# How to display components of a child `router-view` that is nested within parent `router-view` in Vue JS?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I am trying to create a side menu (Dashboard's side menu with content) and I have to use multiple `router-view`.

First `router-view` is in `App.vue` that contains all the component.

```
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
```

and the second `router-view` exists within above `router-view` as:

```
  <div class="dashboard">
    <Sidebar />
    <div class="content">
      <router-view name="content"></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
```

According to below `router/index.js` code, if user visits `/` link, he will be redirected to dashboard page.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    name: "Dashboard",
    component: dashboard,
  },
  {
    path: "/messages",
    name: "Messages",
    components: {
      content: Messages,
    },
  },
  {
    path: "/profile",
    name: "Profile",
    components: {
      content: Profile,
    },
  },
  {
    path: "/settings",
    name: "Settings",
    components: {
      content: Settings,
    },
  },
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "Overview",
    components: {
      content: Overview,
    },
  },
];
```

and within above `Sidebar` component, there're links that upon clicking it shows the content of that link on right side (as in dashboard):

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="title">
        Simple Sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="menu-items">
        <router-link to="" active-class="active" tag="button" exact class="side-btn">
            <div class="link-container">
                Overview
            </div>
        </router-link>
        <router-link to="/messages" active-class="active" tag="button" exact class="side-btn">
            <div class="link-container">
                Messages
            </div>
        </router-link>
        // ....
    </div>
</div>
```

for the second `router-view` I added a name as :

```
<router-view name="content"></router-view>
```

and then I identified it in `router/index.js` as:

```
  {
    path: "/messages",
    name: "Messages",
    components: {
      content: Messages,
    },
  },
```

but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me debug and solve this issue, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [nested route](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html#nested-routes) requires `children` route configs, which is missing from `Dashboard`'s route config.

Move the route config of `Messages` into `Dashboard`'s `children` array:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    name: "Dashboard",
    component: dashboard,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/messages",
        name: "Messages",
        components: {
          content: Messages,
        },
      },
    ]
  },
  //...
]
```